# rbind by for loop with scraping from Webpage

Tags: r, for-loop, rbind

I am trying to scrape data from a webpage and `rbind` it.

#### 1. Scraping Data From Webpage

```
for (i in 1:10) {

url <- paste0("https://www.nest.co.uk/pendants?page=",i)

Pandents <- read_html(url)

PanInfos <- html_nodes(Pandents, css = '.fn.name')

PanInfos[1] %>% html_nodes('.brand') %>% html_text()
```

#### 2. extract "BRANDS"

```
BRANDS <- PanInfos %>% html_nodes('.brand') %>% html_text()
```

#### 3. Removing unicode and extract "SHORTNAMES"

```
panShortnames <- PanInfos %>% html_nodes('.short-name') %>% html_text()

SHORT1 <-  gsub(pattern = '\U00A0', replacement = " ", panShortnames)

SHORTNAMES <-  gsub(pattern = '\U2013', replacement = "-", SHORT1)
```

#### 4. extract "PRICE"

```
PriceInfos <- html_nodes(Pandents, css = '.info')

PRICE <- PriceInfos %>% html_nodes('.price') %>% html_text()
```

#### 5. making Data Frame with using "IF"

```
if ( i == 1) {
  data1<- data.frame(BRANDS, SHORTNAMES, PRICE)
}

else if (i ==2) {
  data2<- data.frame(BRANDS, SHORTNAMES, PRICE)
}
###......

else (i ==10) {
  data10<- data.frame(BRANDS, SHORTNAMES, PRICE)
}  
}
```

#### 6. make FINAL Data Frame

```
FINAL <- rbind(data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7, data8, data9,data10)
```

This is my first R practice and now I finally know R's really complicated.
What I wanna do is extract data from webpage and make one csv file.
But it doesn't work at all. I really need your advise. What's wrong with mine?
And is there any easier way to do

Comment: *"But it doesn't work at all."* How does it not work? Please provide the error message.

Comment: Error in data.frame(BRANDS, SHORTNAMES, PRICE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 24, 0

Comment: And before that, there are no creation of data1, data2....data10 Data frame.

Comment: Errors and corroborating info (like your last two comments) should really be included directly in the question. Comments are often skimmed if not skipped, so it's better if significant details be retained primarily/solely in the question itself.

Comment: What is the value of `i` when this fails? What do the components (e.g., `BRAND`, `SHORTNAMES`, and `PRICE`) look like when the command fails? How (if wrong) are they *supposed* to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to get at?

Load libraries for webscraping

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
```

First, create a list of dummy variables to store the dat

```
pass <- paste0("dat", 1:10)
```

Take each page and store the information into dat1 - dat10

```
for(i in 1:10){

  url <- paste0("https://www.nest.co.uk/pendants?page=", i)

  assign(pass[i], read_html(url))

}
```

For future convenience of looping make a list of dat1 - dat10

```
datalist <- list(dat1, dat2, dat3, dat4, dat5, dat6, dat7, dat8, dat9, dat10)
```

setup dummy dataframe

```
brand <- paste0("brand", 1:24)

dfbrand <- as.data.frame(brand)
```

loop through dat1 - dat10, extract name info and append to dfbrand

The "length(BRANDS) <- nrow(dfbrand)" ensures number of rows are the same to ensure cbind works

```
for (i in datalist){

  PanInfos <- html_nodes(i, css = '.fn.name')

  BRANDS <- 
    PanInfos %>% 
    html_nodes('.brand') %>% 
    html_text()

  length(BRANDS) <- nrow(dfbrand)

  BRANDS <- as.data.frame(BRANDS)

  dfbrand <- cbind(dfbrand, BRANDS)

}
```

Same goes with name and price, I didn't see any differences in extracting the name and using gsubs so I excluded those steps

```
name <- paste0("name", 1:24)

dfname <- as.data.frame(name)

for (i in datalist){

  PanInfos <- html_nodes(i, css = '.fn.name')

  NAMES <- 
    PanInfos %>% 
    html_nodes('.short-name') %>% 
    html_text()

  length(NAMES) <- nrow(dfname)

  NAMES <- as.data.frame(NAMES)

  dfname <- cbind(dfname, NAMES)

}

price <- paste0("price", 1:24)

dfprice <- as.data.frame(price)

for (i in datalist){

  PanInfos <- html_nodes(i, css = '.info')

  PRICE <- 
    PanInfos %>% 
    html_nodes('.price') %>% 
    html_text()

  length(PRICE) <- nrow(dfprice)

  PRICE <- as.data.frame(PRICE)

  dfprice <- cbind(dfprice, PRICE)

}
```

Finally, take each row of data and append them into a new dataframe

the +1 in the [i+1] is used since our original dummy dataframe contains placeholder information in column1

```
pass2 <- paste0("scrapeddat", 1:10)

for (i in 1:10) {

  assign(pass2[i], data.frame(dfbrand[i+1], dfname[i+1], dfprice[i+1]))

}
```

Let me know if this helps or if you have additional questions!

Comment: seriously, you are genius

Comment: i really appreciate your kindness

Comment: But is there any easier way to make        datalist <- list(dat1, dat2, dat3, dat4, dat5, dat6, dat7, dat8, dat9, dat10) ?? when I'm tryin to make 100 of dat

Comment: for (i in datalist){

  PanInfos <- html_nodes(i, css = '.info')

  PRICE <- 
    PanInfos %>% 
    html_nodes('.price') %>% 
    html_text()

Comment: ^ another Question! what should i do if i extract whether ('.price') node or ('.now') node? because of SALE in that page, normal price extracted well, but sale price didn't extracted.

Comment: You can use `df_list = mget(ls(pattern = "dat[0-9]"))` for the first question. I think it's possible to extract the sale price but i don't actually know how to set it to the right row, I'm fairly new to XML too so hopefully someone else could help on that.

Comment: Once again, I really appreciate your kindness and effort for me. Thanks :)